# PHP get data thats between 5 and 10 mins ago

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, time

I have a *simple* script showing users logged in now (determinded by if they have loaded a page in the last 5 mins) code:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_actions WHERE timestamp > date_sub(now(), interval 5 minute) GROUP BY user_id");
```

I now want to do this for users who was logged in between 5 and 10 mins ago, is this possible?

Comment: Sure. `timestamp BETWEEN date_sub(now(),interval 10 minute) AND date_sub(now(),interval 5 minute)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` to get current time of query execution. So

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_actions WHERE timestamp > (UNIX_TIMESTAMP-300000) OR timestamp > (UNIX_TIMESTAMP-600000) GROUP BY user_id");
```

and use convert minutes to milliseconds. Do change OR to AND depending on how you want to.

Answer (score 2):

Try [`BETWEEN AND`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) for this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM user_actions 
WHERE timestamp BETWEEN date_sub(now(), interval 5 minute) AND date_sub(now(), interval 10 minute) 
GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: This is showing as 0 even though I have an row in the database from 8 mins ago?

Comment: Can you post some sample data?

Answer (score 0):

```
require_once('DBconnection.php');
$con->query("SELECT required_rows FROM some_table WHERE timestamp BETWEEN date_sub(now(), interval 5 minute) AND date_sub(now(), interval 10 minute) GROUP BY id");
```

**Also compatible with prepared statements too**